# Problem with world generation in unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to create a world generation using two noise maps (altitude noise and moisture noise). I create maps of these noises and set them in the inspector to values between 0 and 1.

I want to get result like [this](https://medium.com/@henchman/adventures-in-procedural-terrain-generation-part-1-b64c29e2367a):

```
If Elevation < 1000 
{
    If Moisture < 50: Desert
    Else Forest
}
```

And it seems that I did it as it should, but for some reason the generation does not work correctly:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
for (int x=0; x < tilemap.Width; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < tilemap.Height; y++)
    {
        // Get height at this position
        var height = noiseMap[y * tilemap.Width + x];
        
        var moisureHeight = moisureMap[y * tilemap.Width + x];

        // Loop over our configured tile types
        for (int i = 0; i < TileTypes.Length; i++)
        {   
            var TileType = TileTypes[i];

            for (var j = 0; j < TileType.MoisureValues.Length; j++)
            {   
                // If the height is smaller or equal then use this tiletype
                if (height <= TileType.Height)
                {   
                    if (moisureHeight <=TileType.MoisureValues[j].MoisureHeight)
                    {
                        tilemap.SetTile(x, y, (int)TileType.MoisureValues[j].GroundTile);
                        break;    
                    }
                                        
                }                          
            }         
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it's look worked , just color diffrence ?

Comment: @TimChang it using only element 2 from inspector (in my screenshot)

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing your `noiseMap` and `moisureMap` ... have you tried setting some breakpoints and [debugging your code](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html) ?

Comment: @derHugo here is my noises [link](https://github.com/HuggMeRN/Res.git)